# Problema con decimales en Java

Tags: java, formato

Estoy realizando pequeños problemas como practica para el curso que estoy siguiendo de Java.

Quiero que cuando yo introduzca dos resultados, como por ejemplo:

50.000 y 20.000 el resultado que obtenga sea 30.000 y no 30.0

Por el contrario cuando escribo 50.000 y 42.521 el resultado si es completo

Gracias

**CODIGO**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Supermercado {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        String pago = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el monto pagado por el cliente");

        double pago2 = Double.parseDouble(pago);

        String precio = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el valor del producto");

        double precio2 = Double.parseDouble(precio);

        double cambio = pago2 - precio2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El cambio es igual a " + cambio);

    }
}
```

Comment: el código va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor, no publiques imágenes con código, sino directamente el texto del mismo. Un saludo.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El valor internamente es el mismo, solo estás tratando de representarlo, por eso te recomiendo usar

```
String.format(java.util.Locale.US,"%.3f", cambio);
```

El primer argumento es la configuración local que te permitirá saber si se usan puntos o comas en los decimales, lo segundo es una cadena de formato en la que le dice que va a recibir un número con punto flotante (`%f`) pero que lo va a formatear siempre con tres decimales `%.3f`.

Ese método te regresa una cadena con el formato ya aplicado.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El cambio es igual a " + String.format(java.util.Locale.US,"%.3f", cambio));
```

Saludos.

Comment: Ese método debe ser remplazado en que sección Ruslan?. Antes había intentado con el printf y %.3f y no me funcionó. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Pues utilizar la siguiente línea:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");     
System.out.println(formatter.format(42.0));
```

Puedes utilizar la clase NumberFormat y DecimalFormat para darle formato al resultado que quieres imprimir, tu propones la cantidad de ceros después del punto decimal. En el ejemplo de arriba al ejecutarlo me imprime:

```
42.000
```

Comment: No en todo latinoamérica se usa el punto para separar los decimales, sería mejor si tu solución lo tomara en cuenta

Comment: @RuslanLópez en su forma actual, `formatter` utilizaría el _default_ del equipo donde corre. En mi opinión, con eso sería suficiente para que sea `.` o `,` dependiendo de dónde se ejecute el programa.

Comment: El problema es que muchas veces nuestros familiares migrantes nos envían equipos con el sistema preinstalado en el país que lo compraron, no creo que esté de más agregarle a la respuesta como especificar la configuración local de un país.